# Tool for analysing and stepping through code?

Tags: python, code-analysis, profiling

Recently I came across a tool which could analyse running python code and produced a visual representation similar to a code editor to allow one to step through the different parts of the code, seeing how many times each part was called, execution time, etc.

I can't find the reference to it again. Would anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what I was looking for: [Code Investigator](http://codeinvestigator.googlepages.com/main)

> CodeInvestigator is a tracing tool for Python programs. All run time information is recorded. Read your code together with its run time details in a Firefox browser. See what your program did when it ran.

Answer (score 2):

[cProfile](http://pydoc.org/2.5.1/cProfile.html) or [Hotshot](http://docs.python.org/library/hotshot.html).

Comment: No, it was neither of those. It may have used those libraries, but it gave a very handy visual interface which looked like highlighted code in an editor.

Comment: have a look at the David's/f3lix's answer I think thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[**RunSnakeRun**](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) is user interface for cProfile/Hotshot (see [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350864/tool-for-analysing-and-stepping-through-code/1350872#1350872)), which also provides a visualization of the profiling data.

Another useful link might be the link to the **PyCon2009 Talk [Introduction to Python Profiling (#65)](http://us.pycon.org/2009/conference/schedule/event/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/python/index.html) with python plug-in?

Comment: Nope, although that looks good, it was IIRC a stand-alone tool not an IDE extension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Python Call Graph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/)?